# Loop through Flask request.json

Tags: python, json, flask

How do I loop through a JSON Array with Objects I got from a Post Method?

```
app.route(API_BASE_URL + 'Sensor/<string:sensor_name>', methods=['POST'])
def add_value(sensor_name):
    data = request.json()['data']
    for obj in data:
        sensor_value = obj['value']
        dtstamp = obj['timestamp']
        user_name = obj['user']
```

My Post Request:

```
{"data":[{
    "value" : 24,
    "timestamp" : "2017-02-17 22:22:22",
    "user" : "TE"
},
{
    "value" : 26,
    "timestamp" : "2017-02-17 22:22:22",
    "user" : "TE"
}]}
```

Why does not this work?

I do not get an error from the IDE but from Postman I receive this:

```
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: "Why does not this work?"   How would we know if you don't show us the error?

Comment: Im on mobile currently and only copied some code and the requests from a gist. I'll post the exact error later

Comment: @DeepSpace I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.json` is not a function. `.json` is an attribute that holds the dictionary, so you need to change `data = request.json()['data']` to `data = request.json['data']`.